# Can't connect to Tor while on school wifi

Tags: bridge, proxy, socks, connection

below are the logs:

```
2024-01-24 17:00:42.514 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
2024-01-24 17:00:42.515 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
2024-01-24 17:00:42.518 [WARN] Port "0" out of range
2024-01-24 17:00:42.518 [WARN] Port "0" out of range
2024-01-24 17:00:42.518 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: HTTPSProxy failed to parse or resolve. Please fix.
2024-01-24 17:00:42.520 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
2024-01-24 17:00:42.522 [WARN] Port "0" out of range
2024-01-24 17:00:42.523 [WARN] Port "0" out of range
2024-01-24 17:00:42.523 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: HTTPSProxy failed to parse or resolve. Please fix.
2024-01-24 17:00:43.865 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
2024-01-24 17:00:43.878 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2024-01-24 17:00:43.878 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
2024-01-24 17:00:44.513 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
2024-01-24 17:00:46.785 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
```

I'm trying to connect to Tor from my school WiFi and I'm stuck on the 'Establishing a Connection' screen, I've tried different bridges and have had the same result. Wondering if anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Hi, can you give some more details (which operating system, Tor Browser or some other software, what kind of bridge did you use)?

Comment: Im on MacOS, Tor Browser, and ive used obfs4, snowflake, and meek-azure which all dont work

Answer (score -1):

You need your own private bridge, set it up on DigitalOcean. Also a wireguard can be attempted to go to the outside world - it breaks some DPI's through

Comment: This won't solve the problem of the OP-

Comment: it will, with a big probability: looking at the log - as it was sent - there's either a DPI at work or per-IP ban list, maybe both. So - private obfs bridge with unpublished descriptor and WireGuard are worth trying for sure! It helped in similar cases even to me